# Retrieve Contact Object Fields via Amscript and Concat Fields to Url

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, standard-objects

I'm retrieving Object:Contact, such as: Identity_code__c and Device_Code__c' (these fields are mapped out from custom object named Guest_User__c) below is my code, but whenever i send it to a contact, i can't retrieve the values for the fields:

```
%%[
var @Email, @SF, @row, @Id, @Icode, @Dcode 

Set @Email = Email
Set @SF = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'Identity_code__c,Device_Code__c', 'Email', '=',@Email)


IF RowCount(@SF) > 0 THEN
SET @row = row(@SF,1) 

    Set @Id = FIELD(@row,"Id")
    Set @Icode = FIELD(@row,"Identity_code__c")
    Set @Dcode = FIELD(@row,"Device_Code__c")
ENDIF

SET @url = "https:// test. url. com/verify/"
SET @concatURL = concat(@url,@Icode,":",@Dcode)

]%%
```

Your url: `%%value(@concatURL)%%`

I'm getting result on email as https:// test .url .com/verify/:

Could be the problem here: `Set @Email = Email`? if yes what field can i use in order to get the contact field details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest retrieving the `emailaddr` [**personalization string**](https://ampscript.guide/book/subscriber-data-strings/) from the send context and then outputting your variables for debugging:

```
%%[

var @Email, @SF, @rowCount, @url, @concatURL, @row, @Id, @Icode, @Dcode

set @Email = AttributeValue("emailaddr")

output(concat("email: ", @Email))

set @SF = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'Identity_code__c,Device_Code__c', 'Email', '=', @Email)
set @rowCount = RowCount(@SF)

output(concat("<br>RowCount: ", @rowCount))

IF @rowCount > 0 THEN

    set @row = row(@SF,1) 
    set @Id = field(@row, "Id")
    set @Icode = field(@row, "Identity_code__c")
    set @Dcode = field(@row, "Device_Code__c")

ENDIF

set @url = "https://test.url.com/verify/"
set @concatURL = concat(@url, @Icode,":",@Dcode)

]%%
<br>concatURL: %%=v(@concatURL)=%%
```

Here's an example using the Subscriber Key for the retrieve:

```
   %%[

var @sk, @SF, @rowCount, @url, @concatURL, @row, @Id, @Icode, @Dcode

set @sk = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")

output(concat("sk: ", @sk))

set @SF = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'Identity_code__c,Device_Code__c', 'ID', '=', @sk)
set @rowCount = RowCount(@SF)

output(concat("<br>RowCount: ", @rowCount))

IF @rowCount > 0 THEN

    set @row = row(@SF,1) 
    set @Id = field(@row, "Id")
    set @Icode = field(@row, "Identity_code__c")
    set @Dcode = field(@row, "Device_Code__c")

ENDIF

set @url = "https://test.url.com/verify/"
set @concatURL = concat(@url, @Icode,":",@Dcode)

]%%
<br>concatURL: %%=v(@concatURL)=%%
```

**Reference:**

- [**RetrieveSalesforceObjects**](https://ampscript.guide/book/retrievesalesforceobjects/)
- [**Output**](https://ampscript.guide/book/output/)
- [**Concat**](https://ampscript.guide/book/concat/)

Comment: Still unable to get any results from the debug, still aint pulling any data from Contact, is there any example ampscripts that can pull field values from Contact Object that will work on email for Journey Builder eg. firstname , lastname and any custom field values? 

thank you.

Comment: You might try the retrieve with the Subscriber Key instead.  I've updated my answer to include an example.

Comment: Awesome that one did the trick, was able to pull values using set @sk = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey") Thanks a lot.